# CUDA's device properties in HIP

Tags: c++, gpu, amd-rocm, hip

My task is to port caches' latency measurement program written in CUDA to HIP, and for that i need to get characteristics of GPU.

I'm using HIP 4.5.0, and the problem is that for some data from CUDA's `deviceInfo`, there're no (direct) analogues from HIP.

They are:

1. (Max) Shared memory per multiprocessor

In CUDA, [`sharedMemPerMultiprocessor`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/structcudaDeviceProp.html#structcudaDeviceProp_16cede1829516e86917f0842a5f6498c8) exists. When talking about HIP, i found [`maxSharedMemoryPerMultiprocessor`](https://rocm-developer-tools.github.io/HIP/structhipDeviceProp__t.html#aa1a32a7f387f6da845db7b228711fce8). Are they the same? Or first one is always less or equal to the second one and thus can't be replaced?

2. Registers per multiprocessor

In CUDA - [`regsPerMultiprocessor`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/structcudaDeviceProp.html#structcudaDeviceProp_1de02e669caefcadadaaa42877b08e80a). In HIP - non-existent (according to this [page](https://rocm-developer-tools.github.io/HIP/structhipDeviceProp__t.html#a73c1c21648a901799ff6bef83c11135b)). Is there's a workaround for capturing number of registers per multiprocessor in this case?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: @YouJin hi! sort of:
1. For `sharedMem..` the values on Nvidia side are the same, for AMD - had to take them for granted. 
2. For `regsPerMultiprocessor` - switched to `regsPerSM` value. Under all tested arch's for my BA thesis, the former was equal to latter + found a formula for verification of my idea, but no sufficient proofs to confirm/reject it :(